# Return view to partial dynamic change with button push to jquery ajax return on laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-blade

I want to use $returndata like data from controller to view

```
return view('mainpage')->with('returndata', $returndata);
```

How to write the controller return and the ajax success process?

view mainpage.blade.php

```
@if(isset($returndata)!)
<span>{{$returndata->product}}</sapn>
@endif
```

the same page

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="ajaxbutton">ajaxbutton</button>
```

jquery function

```
$('button[name="ajaxbutton"]').on('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
           headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
      url :'{{asset("ajax_controller")}}',
      type:'POST',
      data:{id:id,name:name},
      dataType : 'json',
      success : function(returndata)
      {
                                               ???????
      } 
   })

})

Route::post('ajax_controller','BackController@ajax_controller');
```

BackController

```
  public function ajax_controller()
    {
      ........  
      return  $retundata;                     ????????
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can return the values like this

```
 public function ajax_controller(Request $request)
 {
    return response()->json([
      'retundata' => $request->all()
    ], 200);              
 }
```

Comment: I try it.But nothing happen.  Does ajax success function is the same writing?

Comment: @robspin sorry, do not notice that you were sent a post, maybe the error is because you do not receive the post in the function, modify my example so you would notice.